# How do you integrate bbdb with notmuch?

Tags: bbdb, notmuch

I wonder if anyone has gotten BBDB to work with notmuch. I'm looking for the behaviour I had with gnus, where I would type a name from BBDB, press tab and be presented with options to choose from.

The [Notmuch 'emacstips' page](https://notmuchmail.org/emacstips/) is frustratingly brief...

> bbdb is a contact database for emacs that works quite nicely together
>   with message mode, including address autocompletion.

...and doesn't say actually how to integrate bbdb into notmuch.

I have tried to customize the `notmuch-address-command` with the value `bbdb` but this raises the error

> Searching for program: No such file or directory, bbdb

I have the following relevant lines in my init.el

```
(require 'bbdb)
(bbdb-initialize 'message)
(bbdb-insinuate-message)
(setq bbdb-complete-mail-allow-cycling t)
```

My Emacs is GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8) of 2019-04-12